# How do function pointers in C work? - Specific example

Tags: c, function-pointers

So, I realize this question has been asked before. I still don't understand the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    volatile int (*fp)();
    char buffer[64];
    fp = 0;

    if(fp){
        printf("Buffer Overflow, jumping to %p", fp);
        fp();
    }
}
```

The first line declares the function pointer fp. The third lines advices the value 0, which should be equivalent to address 0 (`&0`), to the function pointer. This is now the content of the memory address that the pointer is pointing to. The if-statement, therefore, should never become true. Still, should become true, it will be executed. If it was executed, the printf-function prints the address that is now stored within my pointer fp.

But what is the last line (`fp()`) doing? To me, it looks as if I was trying to call the function fp() the address of which my pointer fp is pointing to. But this function has not been defined in this code. So, what is this doing?

Comment: *"value 0 ... This is now the content of the memory address that the pointer is pointing to"* That's not how it works. The pointer itself is changed to `0`, not the pointed memory.

Comment: It is trying to call whatever function whose address is in the function pointer `fp`.

Comment: This `fp();` let your code crashed, btw you forgot so many `;` in the sample code. Please read [How to Ask a Question on Stack Overflow](https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Richard Chambers: thx so much, I think I get it now!

Comment: Where did you get the code from? Wasn't there some description? It seems to be a (incomplete/incorrect) way to illustrate how to exploit a buffer overflow.

Comment: @ 4386427: Yeah, I don't have it with me atm. There was another function besides the main() function. This other function gets called when you achieve that the address that fp() points to equals the address of this other function

Answer (score 1):

The `volatile` qualifier indicates that the value of `fp` may change at any time *outside of the control of the code in this function* (this prevents the compiler from performing certain optimizations on `fp`).  In practice, you'd use the qualifier on something that's been memory-mapped, or a global that can be modified by an interrupt, or something similar.  In this particular instance, there's no reason to expect `fp` to be changed by something external to this code.

But, the intent of the code is that *if* `fp` is somehow changed to a non-`NULL` value (that is, set to point to a function), then this code will print that pointer value and then *execute the pointed-to function*.

Answer (score 0):

This "code" assumes something which is guaranteed by the C standard.

`fp = 0;` - assigns the fp with NULL pointer (and emits the warning)

You should use `fp = NULL;` or if you are not sure the internal representation of the NULL pointer in memory (in your implementation are zeroes) `fp = (int (*)())0;`

Now the program assumes that the fp will be placed **after** the buffer which is not guaranteed in C. Implementation may order variables its own way.

But even assuming that order - if the buffer is written out of the bounds (but it will work only if this will less than sizeof(fp) and the data written is not zero) the `fp` will become not NULL. But you can't call it as it will contain a random address and your program will crash

Comment: `NULL`is equal to zero, it is not any special in C unlike other languages such as JAVA, basically it's a `#define NULL 0`

Comment: @AhmedAboumalek: in C (unlike C++) `NULL` is usually typed to a `void *`.  See http://c-faq.com/null/nullor0.html

Comment: @AhmedAboumalek define NULL this way in the C program and you will get uncountable warnings :)

Comment: Thanks for the link @cdarke. What I probably was thinking was about the comparaison aspect as comparing a variable to `NULL` is interchangeable with comparing it to `0`